# How to convert Webpack 4 plugin to Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack

How do I convert this plugin that worked on Webpack 4 to Webpack 5?

More specifically, the `plugin()` function no longer works. How do I replace this to support Webpack 5?

```js
const ConstDependency = require('webpack/lib/dependencies/ConstDependency');
const NullFactory = require('webpack/lib/NullFactory');

class StaticAssetPlugin {
  constructor(localization, options, failOnMissing) {
    this.options = options || {};
    this.localization = localization;
    this.functionName = this.options.functionName || '__';
    this.failOnMissing = !!this.options.failOnMissing;
    this.hideMessage = this.options.hideMessage || false;
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    const { localization } = this;
    const name = this.functionName;

    compiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation, params) => {
      compilation.dependencyFactories.set(ConstDependency, new NullFactory());
      compilation.dependencyTemplates.set(ConstDependency, new ConstDependency.Template());
    });

    compiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation, data) => {
      data.normalModuleFactory.plugin('parser', (parser, options) => {
        // should use function here instead of arrow function due to save the Tapable's context
        parser.plugin(`call ${name}`, function staticAssetPlugin(expr) {
          let param;
          let defaultValue;
          switch (expr.arguments.length) {
            case 1:
              param = this.evaluateExpression(expr.arguments[0]);
              if (!param.isString()) return;
              defaultValue = param = param.string;
              break;
            default:
              return;
          }
          let result = localization(param);

          const dep = new ConstDependency(JSON.stringify(result), expr.range);
          dep.loc = expr.loc;
          this.state.current.addDependency(dep);
          return true;
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = StaticAssetPlugin;
```

Are there any migration guides for plugin creation that I can follow? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find suitable environment details needed to run the plugin [here](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#upgrade-webpack-4-and-its-pluginsloaders).
Along with this, you must care about how to access event hooks

```
compiler.hooks.someHook.tap('MyPlugin', (params) => {
  /* ... */
});
```

You can get more about it [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/)

---

**Converting your existing plugin to Webpack 5, you can tap a specific event hook and get it done.**
If you try to run the plugin with the above code with Webpack 5, you will get the below error.

[image: plugin-console-error]

Many articles will suggest you update `webpack-cli` which is not enough.

```
const ConstDependency = require('webpack/lib/dependencies/ConstDependency');
const NullFactory = require('webpack/lib/NullFactory');

const PLUGIN_NAME = 'StaticAssetPlugin';

class StaticAssetPlugin {
  constructor(localization, options, failOnMissing) {
    this.options = options || {};
    this.localization = localization;
    this.functionName = this.options.functionName || '__';
    this.failOnMissing = !!this.options.failOnMissing;
    this.hideMessage = this.options.hideMessage || false;
  }
  
  apply(compiler) {
    const { localization } = this;
    const name = this.functionName;
    
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(PLUGIN_NAME, (compilation, params) => {
      compilation.dependencyFactories.set(ConstDependency, new NullFactory());
      compilation.dependencyTemplates.set(ConstDependency, new ConstDependency.Template());
    });
    
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(PLUGIN_NAME, (compilation, data) => {
      data.normalModuleFactory.hooks.parser.for('javascript/auto').tap(PLUGIN_NAME, (parser, options) => {
        parser.hooks.expression.for('this').tap(PLUGIN_NAME, function staticAssetPlugin(expr) {
          let param;
          let defaultValue;
          switch (expr.arguments.length) {
            case 1:
            param = this.evaluateExpression(expr.arguments[0]);
            if (!param.isString()) return;
            defaultValue = param = param.string;
            break;
            default:
            return;
          }
          let result = localization(param);
          
          const dep = new ConstDependency(JSON.stringify(result), expr.range);
          dep.loc = expr.loc;
          this.state.current.addDependency(dep);
          return true;
        });
      })
    });
  }
}

module.exports = StaticAssetPlugin;
```

**Importantly you have to decide which event hook you need to access from `compiler` and `parser`. You will get a list of popular hooks here, for the [compiler](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/) for [parser](https://webpack.js.org/api/parser/#hooks).**

You can get a complete list of hooks just by accessing hooks.

for compiler

```
console.log(compiler.hooks);
```

for parser

```
console.log(parser.hooks);
```

You can choose accordingly.